# symbolic link for last created file

Tags: asynchronous, symlink

I would like to know if is it possible to create a symbolic link which points to the last created file of a specific directory.

I have a folder which contains several HTML reports and I need a symlink for get the last generated report.

Because of I don't know when a new report has been generated I must use a script on the crontab, so I'd like to know if a better way to do could exist.

Comment: I think you need to use `find` to [order by time](http://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified) and [ignore symbolic links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141480/ls-content-of-a-directory-ignoring-symlinks) then take the last line (using `tail`) and then use `ln -sf old new`.

Comment: Yes but in that way I must check every time if a new file has been created or not by a cron script.

Comment: Well you could have a daemon process checking using some sort of filesystem notification (inotify, etc.).